# How do I extend the client's timeout on making a .NET web service post?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services

I am making a post from a .NET console app to a .NET web service.  I know that the timeout on the server side is 20 min, but if my client takes more than 100 seconds to post my data to that service then I get a timeout exception.  How would I tell my client to wait the available 20 min to timeout?

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in configuration?

Answer (score 6):

on the client side, your webservice object has a timeout value. It should be pretty easy to set by going:

```
myServiceInstance.Timeout = 1200000
```

for 20 minutes

Answer (score 2):

You need to verify that <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200"/> exists in the web.config on the webservice itself to confirm your 20 minutes.

The service proxy class instance in your console app also needs to be set. There is a Timeout property to set (in milliseconds) so you would do something like this:

MyServiceClass myService = new MyServiceClass();
myService.Timeout = 1200000;

Comment: We need the Gmailish notifications that someone has posted to this question for us people who don't type as fast as the others ;->

Comment: +1 for mentioning that you have to do it on the client and on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Yup the `ServiceInstance.Timeout` is the property to set.

I blogged about it here
http://stackpanel.com/blog/2008/10/client-timeout-accessing-asmx-web-service/

Comment: Blog link Page Not Found (404)